# Problems getting app to post to a page

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, post, graph, http-post

The goal of my app is purely to take news items, created on my website, and have them posted on the wall of my facebook page automatically. (not a user, but a business page). I have succeeded in getting the app to post to my user wall, but there several issues with that. For one, I need it to post on my BUSINESS page, and the access_token expires. I don't want it to expire, it needs to stay active so that any post to my website will continue to post to facebook.

Does anybody know of any straight forward way to doing this? The on that got me this far was this: http://nocturnsoft.com/devblog/?p=906. In the end, the two things I need to know is how to post to a business page using graph API, and I need to know how to extend the life of my access_token.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need several things to achieve this:

- Active `access_token` for user who is admin of that page.
- `manage_pages` and `publish_stream` permissions granted by that user.
- Page `access_token` (which you can get from `accounts` connection of `user` object)
  `GET http://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts` (will return array of details for every pages user own, with `access_token` included for every page)
- Create [`post`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#posts) by issuing `POST` requests to `http://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed` using page `access_token`.

As you said `access_token` is something that can expire, you can't disable this (and it's not something bad, actually you can **for a limited time** because `offline_access` permission exists, but **it's deprecated**) but you can extend the expire period for up to 60 days as described in [Deprecation of Offline Access Permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/) developers blog post.