# Posting to a page with graph api

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am a FB user who has rights to post to a page using the FB GUI. I want to post a status update to the page using the graph API v2. Following [these](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens) instructions I get a user token with a manage_pages and user_status permission checked. Then I submit a query `me/accounts` and get back this:

```
  "name": "My Page", 
  "access_token": "token", 
  "perms": [
    "EDIT_PROFILE", 
    "CREATE_CONTENT", 
    "MODERATE_CONTENT", 
    "CREATE_ADS", 
    "BASIC_ADMIN"
  ], 
  "id": "number"
```

If I then do the following with facepy (python wrapper)

```
graph = GraphAPI('token')
graph.post('number/feed', message='Hello world')
```

I get the error OAuthError: `[200] (#200) The target user has not authorized this action`

What am I doing wrong? I found this answer [Problems getting app to post to a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066941/problems-getting-app-to-post-to-a-page) but it says I need publish_stream permissions. This seems to be an old answer as I no longer see this permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permission `publish_actions` is required in order to [post a feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/feed/#publish). Since you are not including this, you are getting this error.

Another thing, `user_status` is not required for publishing purpose, you can ignore this.